# Move axis in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors. The main tensor is as follows:

```
array([[[ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217]],

       [[ 450,  607,  493,  662],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[ 950, 1277, 1028, 1335],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]]], dtype=int32)
```

I want to move this tensor according to the following tensor:

```
array([0, 2, 5], dtype=int32)
```

The above tensor contains the axis we want the current axis to move to.

The final tensor should look like this:

```
array([[[ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
        [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[ 450,  607,  493,  662],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[ 950, 1277, 1028, 1335],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for `numpy.moveaxis` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)

Comment: @offeltoffel But I want this in tensorflow.

Comment: Sorry! Then it is `tf.transpose(tensor_array, perm=[0, 2, 5])`. Have a look at this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose?version=stable

Comment: It's not very clear from the text, but what you want is, for input `[0, 2, 5]`, swap the contents of positions 2 and 5 in axis 0?

Comment: @jdehesa at position 2, I want to content of 1; at position 5, I want the content of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tensorflow **scatter** function [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) for achieving this.

Define your `input` tensor:

```
input = tf.constant([[[ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217]],

   [[ 450,  607,  493,  662],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[ 950, 1277, 1028, 1335],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]]])
```

Since we are interested in only the first 3 elements along zeroth dimension, let's slice it into a new tensor:

```
sliced_input = tf.slice(input, [0, 0, 0], [3, -1, -1])
```

Define your target `indices`:

```
indices = tf.constant([[0], [2], [5]])
```

Define `shapes` of your target `output`, here same as your `input` shape:

```
shape = tf.shape(input)
```

Now use the **scatter** function to get your `output`:

```
output = tf.scatter_nd(indices, sliced_input, shape)
```

`output`:

```
array([[[ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217],
    [ 298, 1217,  298, 1217]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[ 450,  607,  493,  662],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[ 950, 1277, 1028, 1335],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0]]], dtype=int32)
```